# Highlighting selected list item using javascript

Tags: javascript

I know, this question is asked like milion times, but I cant get it to work.

All my html,css and js files are located in same folder.

Below - my code, but I also mad jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgjk3xk2/) .

The code works fine in JSfiddle, but doesnt work on my computer, so i thought it might be something with my html head and linking to javascript file, but it seems to be right.

header of my html file :

```
 <head>
   <title>Nacionālie dārgumi</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul class="main-menu">              
            <li><a class = "main_men_links" href="about.html">PAR PROJEKTU</a></li>
            <li><a class = "main_men_links" href="">NACIONĀLIE DĀRGUMI</a></li>
            <li><a class = "main_men_links" href="">SASNIEGUMI</a></li>
            <li><a class = "main_men_links" href="">SĀKUMS</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

This is my script.js:

```
$(function(){
    console.log('ready');

    $('.main-menu li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        $that = $(this);

        $that.parent().find('li').removeClass('active');
        $that.addClass('active');
    });
})
```

This is my style.css :

```
.active {
    background: black;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your script.js depends on jQuery but I don't see that loaded anywhere.

Comment: You are using jquery.. You need to add jqery js in your header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have jquery library on html head section.
like this using CDN `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Try to add before your main script declaration.
This link only works if you are connected to internet, or download the file so you can use it locally.

Comment: Happy to helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether you have included the reference of Jquery.js in your Header part of HTML or not. As , your script file will not run if you haven't use jquery.js before the script.js load .

Answer (score 1):

Header should be loading jquery.

You can try as below :

```
<head>
   <title>Nacionalie dargumi</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
```

or download jquery.min.js and load it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **jQuery**, so you need to provide the link to the library to get your **script.js** work. Make sure that the CDN library and your local **script.js** are added in this order.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

in your browser Press **F12** and check the tab *Sources* (in Chrome) or 
*Debugger* (in Firefox) to make sure **script.js** is loaded.

You must also see a 'ready' message in your browser console.